# Switching from Fourier transform to Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I have some troubles finding the Laplace transform of :  $~~~f(t)=~e^{a|t|} ~~~(a\le0)~~$ from it's

Fourier transform : $~~\hat{f}(s)=\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-i2\pi st}~dt= \frac{-1}{a+2\pi is}+\frac{1}{-a+2\pi is} = \frac{-1}{a+i\omega}+\frac{1}{-a+i\omega} $   .

I do know that the Laplace transform of : $ \mathcal{L}(f(t))(p)=H(i2\pi s)=H(i\omega)$

so $H(p)$ should be equal to   : $ \frac{-1}{a+p}+\frac{1}{-a+p} $

which is quite different from the result I got from wolphram :

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+transform+of+exp(a*abs(t))

Any pointers to my mistake ?

Thank you .

Comment: Generally the Laplace transform is defined by $$\int_0^\infty  e^{-st}f(t)\ \mathsf dt.$$ Perhaps you are thinking of the bilateral Laplace transform?

Comment: The problem I was treating didn't actually mention that it was the bilateral transform , it just asked for the Laplace transform without actually using the integral but instead just by using the Fourier transform and it's relation to the Laplace transform .

Comment: You have correctly computed the two-sided Laplace transform of $e^{a |t|}$. To get the one-sided Laplace transform, you need $\mathcal F[e^{a |t|} \Theta(t)]$ (generally, $\mathcal F[f(t) e^{-\sigma t}]$ with $\sigma > 0$, but here it is possible to take $\sigma = 0$).

Comment: If we plug $\sigma =0$ wouldn't that just simply give us  the Fourier transform that I have already evaluated above : $\hat{f}(s)= \mathcal F[f(t) ]$ ?

Comment: I'm saying that you need to take the Fourier transform of $e^{a |t|}$ times the unit step function, which is different from the Fourier transform of $e^{a |t|}$. Btw, use @username to make sure that person gets a notification about your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please take this answer for trial and check with care.
Generally the two-sided Laplace transform is more general than Fourier transform and has larger freedom to choose the convergence domain.

We have the function $f(t)=~e^{a|t|}$ with $a\le0$ and we need to find its Laplace transform $F(s)$ in frequency domain $s=\sigma+i\omega$, then
\begin{align}
F(s)&=\mathcal L_{t\to s}[f(t)]=\mathcal F_{t\to\omega}[f(t)e^{-\sigma t}]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\sigma t+a|t|}e^{-i\omega t}\mathsf dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{a|t|}e^{-st}\mathsf dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-at}e^{-st}\mathsf dt+\int_{0}^\infty e^{at}e^{-st}\mathsf dt\\
&\overset{*}{=}\int_0^{\infty}e^{at}e^{-(-s)t}\mathsf dt+\int_{0}^\infty e^{at}e^{-st}\mathsf dt\\
&=\frac{1}{-s-a}+\frac{1}{s-a}\\
&=\frac{2a}{s^2+a^2}
\end{align}